# SPService GetListItems with CAML : can't get example to work

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, spservices

`enter code here`I am using an example I found on codeplex of SPServices with CamlQuery to try to get list item values with where clause on the ID. For whatever reason this doesn't seem to work for me; please help!

```
function getToolInfo(lastID) {

    var CamlQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>" + lastID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    var CamlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>";

  // this let me know that the function is getting called and passed the correct parameter value
  alert('function called and passed last ID of : ' + lastID);
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "FirstList",
    CAMLViewFields: CamlViewFields,
    CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {

        // just load a new variable with the returned value        
        var thisID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
        alert(thisID);

      });
    }
  });
}
```

did I miss something obvious here? basically all the alerts are working except for the last.

Additionally if I remove this line:

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
```

then i can add alert that works. I have double, triple, etc checked the list item with that ID and it is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, the syntax you are using to find the z:row elements no longer works. Use the [SPFilterNode](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPFilterNode) function instead.

Comment: Well, it's in the documentation....in big bold red caption at that. Appreciate it Marc, I missed that. :)

Comment: Maybe I should switch to marquee and flashing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
```

Change your line as I mentioned above. I have tested and it's working also in later versions of jQuery