# SPservice for filtering Dropdown based on parent dropdown

Tags: spservices, camlviewfields

we are $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns  for cascading. Suddenly it stopped working. now I want to use another option of using SPServices with CAML query to display the projects based on Employee selected. Something like this

```
 $().SPServices({
                     operation: "GetListItems",
                     async: false,
                     listName: "Project Allocation",                    
                     CAMLRowLimit: 1,
                     CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + thisUserAccount  + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",   
                     CAMLViewFields:"<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Project' /></ViewFields>"  ,
                     completefunc:null,
                     debug:true
                     });
```

but I am not able to filter.I am new to SPServices. please guide me for this

Answer (score 1):

Your `CAMLQuery: "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + thisUserAccount  + "</Value></Eq></Where>"`

should have "`<Query>`" tags:

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + thisUserAccount  + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
```

Comment: thanks for that. But I am not able to do any filtering. All list items get populated.

Comment: How are you using it? since your completefunc is null...

Comment: as I said I am new to it.i don't know how to do it..i want to filter projects based on employee selected.

Comment: See here for basic usage,  make that work first then try with lookups etc. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39190/spservice-getlistitems-with-caml-cant-get-example-to-work

Answer (score 0):

If the cascade stopped working after a SharePoint upgrade, check out this blog post:
http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/23/office-365-update-changes-display-name-on-required-fields/

I would also suggest to try out [this solution for Cascading Selects](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2014/02/05/get-spell-cascading-selects-1-1-from-my-office-365-site/) (disclaimer: I am the author).

Comment: I have already seen all those posts. Cascading fails because of List view threshold Exceeded.

Comment: I see. I would recommend to include this key info in the question, because in this case the issue is actually with the lookup itself, not with the cascading. You might want to read this: http://sympmarc.com/2014/02/18/getting-around-sharepoints-threshold-limits-for-large-reference-lists/

Comment: thnks Christophe.I read that article too.actually I read almost all articles from net related to SpServices.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding LookupId='TRUE' to your FieldRef. (Also make sure that Employee is the internal name of your field.)

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + thisUserAccount  + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Also, an employee's userID varies depending on what site you're in. It's stored in a hidden list in each site.

```
userID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    fieldNames: {},
    debug: false
});
```